# state update not affecting on view

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

I'm working on a basic react project, where I have react state with object and array, what I'm trying to get done here is I want to push the object to the `images` array, and I want to render that in component, so far I googled things I found few methods to get it done `array.concat` and `array.push`, I tried both methods it's updating the state but it's not affecting on the component

here below is the code I had tried

```
const [proClrData, setProClrData] = useState([
  { color: "black", price: "", qty: "", images: [] },
  { color: "white", price: "", qty: "", images: [] },
  { color: "red", price: "", qty: "", images: [] }
]);
const addImages = (key) => {
  var obj = { src: "", imgdata: "" };
  proClrData[key].images = proClrData[key].images.concat(obj);
  console.log(proClrData);
 };
```

below is component code

```
 {proClrData.length >= 1 &&
    proClrData?.map((clr, key) => {
      return (
        <div key={key}>
          <p className="pt-3 ">{clr.color}</p>
          <div className="form-group">
            <input
              label="Price"
              name="price"
              value={clr?.price}
              type="number"
              fullWidth
              required
            />
          </div>
          <div className="form-group pt-3">
            <input
              label="Quantity"
              name="qty"
              value={clr?.qty}
              type="number"
              fullWidth
              required
            />
          </div>
          <div className="text-end pt-3">
            <button
              variant="contained"
              color="primary"
              onClick={() => addImages(key)}
            >
              Add Images
            </button>
          </div>
          {clr?.images?.map((img, imgkey) => {
            return (
              <div className="form-group pt-3" key={imgkey}>
                <input
                  label="Image"
                  name="images"
                  value=""
                  accept="image/*"
                  type="file"
                  fullWidth
                  required
                />
              </div>
            );
          })}
        </div>
      );
    })}
```

here is [codeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/determined-colden-83b1y?file=/src/App.js) of working code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issue

You are mutating your state object and then ***not*** updating state at all.

```
const addImages = (key) => {
  var obj = { src: "", imgdata: "" };
  proClrData[key].images = proClrData[key].images.concat(obj); // mutation!!
  console.log(proClrData);
};
```

## Solution

Enqueue a state update with the new image data you want in state. Use a functional state update to update from the previous state. Shallow copy the `proClrData` array, and for the matching element, also shallow copy it so it is a new object reference, and then also shallow copy the nested `images` array and append the new object.

```
const [proClrData, setProClrData] = useState([
  { color: "black", price: "", qty: "", images: [] },
  { color: "white", price: "", qty: "", images: [] },
  { color: "red", price: "", qty: "", images: [] }
]);

const addImages = (key) => {
  const obj = { src: "", imgdata: "" };
  setProClrData(data => data.map((el, i) => i === key ? {
    ...el,
    images: [...el.images, obj],
  } : el));
};
```

Since React state updates are asynchronously processed, you will want to move the console log into an `useEffect` hook to log the state *after* it updates and is available on the *next* render.

```
useEffect(() => {
  console.log(proClrData);
}, [proClrData]);
```

Comment: hi thank you for your answer, it seems you didn't mention `obj` getting error of `obj is not defined` here `images: [...el.images, obj],`

Comment: @CodeBug Oops, overzealous code cleanup. Thanks, and sorry about that.

Answer (score 1):

you must call `setProClrData` function to update the state.

Remember that you must not mutate the state, instead you must provide a new reference (a new array in your case) and call the updater function, otherwise React will not be aware that is should re-render the component.

```
const [proClrData, setProClrData] = useState([
  { color: "black", price: "", qty: "", images: [] },
  { color: "white", price: "", qty: "", images: [] },
  { color: "red", price: "", qty: "", images: [] }
]);

const addImages = (key) => {
  const img = { src: "", imgdata: "" };
  const newProClrData = proClrData.map((obj, index) => {
    return index !== key ? data : { ...obj, images: [...data.images, img] };
  });
  setProClrData(newProClrData);
 };
```

Comment: hi Olivier thank you for your time and answer,

Answer (score 0):

You should modify proClrData accordingly and be using setProClrData in order to trigger a re-render.

Check the documentation: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html

Answer (score 0):

You update the state directly

Use the function for this:

```
setProClrData(prev => prev.push() // or concat)
```